# Typescript use of this keyword

Tags: javascript, typescript, performance, this

We are using typescript for our development.
I have also got a review comment that we should not 'this' keyword, it hampers performance.
**Orignal Code:**

```
export Class MyClass
    {
    public myMethod1(Data) {     
            this.myMethod2();
        }

    public myMethod2() {
        }
    }
```

We are using like below to access 'this'.
**After Change:**

```
export Class MyClass
{
public myMethod1(Data) {
        let self = this;
        self.myMethod2();
    }

public myMethod2() {
    }
}
```

So could you please help with implication of using 'this' keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has no effect on performance. But using a variable called `self` and initialize it with `this` at the beginning of each class method may help to avoid unwanted behaviors. For example:

```
Class MyClass
{
    public foo () {
        const self = this;

        callMeLater(function (){
            console.log(self); // "self" is always the instance of MyClass
            console.log(this); // "this" may refer to another object!
        });
    }
}
```

In this example, `self` is captured while it holds a reference to the MyClass instance and in the callback function it still points to the MyClass instance, but in the callback function `this` may refer to something else, it depends on how the callback function is called.

Comment: _using a variable called self and initialize it with this at the beginning of each class method may help to avoid unwanted behaviors_ Actually even at the begging of the method `this` may refer to another object

Comment: @AlekseyL. Yes, that's correct. I assume the method is called this way: `myClassInstance.foo()`.